# Ember-Data: Knowing when a RecordArray is completely populated

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a situation where isLoaded on a DS.RecordArray changes to true but the content, length property of the RecordArray is still empty, 0 at that time and only changes later.

Sample Code(coffeescript):

```
@set('followRequests', App.FollowRequests.find())

...

whenDataLoads: (->

console.log @get('followRequests.isLoaded')
console.log @get('followRequests.length')
@set('content', @get('followRequests').toArray() )

).observes('followRequests.isLoaded')
```

The first log statement is true while the second is 0 and the template which uses this data is empty. When I see the actual AJAX request I see that the request does return an array of records. And the length and content of the RecordArray do change some time later as seen in the Browser console by doing:

`App.Router.myController.get('followRequests').get('length')` ---> 12

However this code(below) does populate the content in the template, but it runs 12 times...

```
whenDataLoads: (->
console.log @get('followRequests.isLoaded')
console.log @get('followRequests.length')

@set('content', @get('followRequests').toArray() )

).observes('followRequests.length')
```

What's the right way to know when the RecordArray is completely populated...??

Comment: I believe this is a bug in ember-data, I opened [an issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/652) on the bug tracker for this. Will be happy to find a workaround though.

Comment: @AdrienCoquio, Thanks, good to know someone else is facing this as well. Will track this, I don't really see any possible workaround though..

Answer (score 2):

Since the time Ember.js uses promises you can do this

```
App.FollowRequests.find().then(function () {
    // This callback will fire when array is loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ember Data beta 1.0.0, you'll request the record(s) using the provided `store` property in a route or controller.

```
// fetch one
var promiseArray = this.store.find('follow_request', follow_request_id);

// fetch all
var promiseArray = this.store.find('follow_request');

// set callbacks on promise array
promiseArray.then(onFollowRequestSuccess, onFollowRequestFailure);

// or set callbacks on promise object
var promise = promiseArray.get('promise');
promise.then(onFollowRequestSuccess, onFollowRequestFailure);

// or use computed property
App.FollowRequestsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    loadedCount: function() {
        return this.get('content.@each').filterBy('isLoaded', true).length;
    }.property('content.@each.isLoaded').cacheable()
});
```